# How to Search Users on the Base of Latitude and Longitude in Users meta_key and meta_value

Tags: search

I have two meta key name (*latitude* and *longitude*) in `wp_usermeta` and its value. I want to search all the users which belongs around 50 or 100 kilometer based of latitude and longitude. How to search by radius?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a pretty confusing way to get the points which are in the radius of another point.

```
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"]; //insert the lat of where you are
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"]; //insert the lng of where you are
$radius = $_GET["radius"]; //insert the radius of KM that you want to search

$multiplier=3959; //miles
$multiplier=($multiplier*1.609344); //use km instead

$users = get_users(array('meta_query' => array(
                                               array(
                                                    'key' => 'latitude',
                                                     'value' => 'XXX', //insert a value just to be safe about https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23268
                                                      'compare' => 'EXISTS' 
                                                      )
                                                )
                         ));

//now we got all our users that have latitude (i assume they also have longitude ^^)
$nearbyusers = array();
foreach($users as $user){
          $lat = get_user_meta($user->ID,'latitude',TRUE); //assuming the user latitude is a meta field named "latitude"
          $lng = get_user_meta($user->ID,'longitude',TRUE); //assuming the user longitude is a meta field named "longitude"
          $distance = ( $multiplier * acos( cos( deg2rad($center_lat) ) * cos( deg2rad( $lat ) ) * cos( deg2rad( $lng ) - deg2rad($center_lng) ) + sin( deg2rad($center_lat) ) * sin( deg2rad( $lat ) ) ) );
          if($distance<$radius) {
              $nearbyusers[] = $user;
          }
}
//now all near by users are in the array $nearbyusers. Do stuff with it! ;)
```

Happy Coding,

Kuchenundkakao

Comment: Can I execute any custom mysql query which returns all the userid from usermeta table?

Comment: Why would you want do that? The "get_users"-function gets you all the users including the id that have the corresponding meta field.